# How fast do particles travel in space?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, particle-physics, kinematics

Does the speed of the particle in space depend on its mass? For example, if the objects are subjected to same energetic phenomena like supernova, do the heavy objects move slower than lightweight objects ?

Comment: Be more specific

Comment: [How long is a piece of string?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389570/how-long-is-a-piece-of-string)

Comment: See Newton's second law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion

Answer (score 1):

In supernova example yes, lighter particles would move faster because it is easier to accelerate them. Other properties of particles being equal.

Particles dont have a particular speed just because of their type or mass. They may have a whole range of speeds depending what event accelerated them.

Some particles like neutrinos are created with a particular speed and then it doesnt change much later usually.

Other particles like electron or proton do interact with electromagnetic fields and can be accelerated to extreme speeds because of it even if they are heavier than neutrinos. So, in this particular example your intuition doesnt work.